# Dash datatable ignores zeros at beginning of string in filter input

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash datatable and I activated the filter option.

I want to filter on "col2", which is a columns of character values. Not numeric.

However, when I filter put "00500" in the filter input on top of the table, the table has 2 rows : the one containing "00500" and "75001", as if the I had filtered on "500" and not on "00500".

It looks like the filter ignores all the zeros at the begining of the string.
How can I solve this and have only the "00500" row when I put "00500" on the filter input ?

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["aabbcc", "bbddcc", "ccddee"],
        "col2": ["00500", "75001", "75013"],
    }
)

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=my_df.to_dict("records"),
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in my_df.columns],
    filter_action="native",
    filter_options={"placeholder_text": "Filtrer", "case": "insensitive"},
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think because the search string is numeric the filter strips the leading zeros even if it treats the data as strings, so you would need to add quotes to your search string to make it match as a (sub)string. You could also set the column type to "numeric" so that leading zeros are ignored consistently (both in the data and the search filter), but it amounts to treat the data as numbers, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the quote trick. My column also rarely contains some non numerical values so I cannot set the column type to numeric.